# Is the marriage supper of the Lamb in heaven or on earth?

Tags: revelation, heaven, earth

Is the supper in heaven or on earth?

> *“And the angel said to me, “Write this: Blessed are those who are invited to the **marriage supper of the Lamb**.” And he said to me, “These are the true words of God.””*
> ‭‭Revelation‬ ‭19:9‬ ‭

And secondly if it’s called a supper are the guests assumed to consume food and drink? Or not?

Comment: All figurative?? “I tell you I will not **drink again** of this fruit of the vine until that day when I drink it new with you **in my Father’s kingdom**.””
‭‭Matt26:29‬, “...To the one who conquers I will grant **to eat** of the tree of life, **which is in the paradise of God**.’”
‭‭Rev2:7‬ ‭ “He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches. To the one who conquers I will give some of the hidden **manna** (food), and ...’”
‭‭Rev‭2:17‬ “...also, on either side of the river, the tree of life with its twelve kinds of fruit, **yielding its fruit** each month...”
‭‭Rev22:2‬

Comment: @NigelJ in all fairness your comment reads like an answer that hasn’t been developed. And besides I’m not sure it’s entirely accurate, for example, the wicked are yet to be cast into the fire Rev19:19 Also angels requiring earthly food? why if there is food in heaven? I’m yet to be convinced heaven is figurative and “spiritualized” when we are given (new) bodies to inhabit

Comment: I agree : the new creation is a reality, not a figure - substantial resurrected and glorified bodies and a real earth and real heavens, re-created.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus is mimicking a Jewish Wedding exactly. First he pays for the bride with his blood and leaves a deposit, the holy spirit. Then he returns home and builds a home next to his fathers house(The new heaven). Then he calls for the bride (rapture) they have a 7 day marriage ceremony(7 years on earth) and the church sees their new home where the marriage is consumated. Then Jesus brings his bride and they come down (The church) wearing fine white linen riding on horses with Jesus (The second coming)After the mess is cleaned up and satan thrown into the pit the new heaven and new earth are revealed. The Old Testament saints will be wearing white robes, The tribulation saints and the 177K Jews will also be wearing white robes. All will attend the marriage supper of the lamb in the New Jerusalem. All guest will be blessed to attend. The bride is never considered a guest at her own wedding. I maybe wrong so please don't rip me a new one. This is my simple understanding of the event.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 177,000? Where is this number from? And you say Jews only? That would account only for 36,000, Judah, Benjamin and Levi.

Comment: +1 for the interesting idea that the wedding guest are different people than the bride. That is something to ponder about.

Answer (score 1):

Is the marriage supper of the Lamb in heaven or on earth?

The marriage supper of the Lamb happens when the new earth is established after Jesus' 2nd coming.

> Revelation 21:1 Then I saw “a new heaven and a **new earth**,” a for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea.

> 9 One of the seven angels who had the seven bowls full of the seven last plagues came and said to me, “Come, I will show you the bride, the **wife of the Lamb**.

That is the church, the believers.

> 10 And he carried me away in the Spirit to a mountain great and high, and showed me the Holy City, **Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God**.

Jerusalem was where the Jews ate the Passovers. New Jerusalem will be the venue for the wedding feast.

> Luke 22:14 When the hour came, Jesus and his apostles reclined at the table. 15And he said to them, “I have eagerly desired to eat this Passover with you before I suffer. 16For I tell you, I will not **eat** it again until it finds fulfillment in the **kingdom of God**.”

As of present time, the kingdom of God is established in us Christians spiritually. After the 2nd coming, it will materialize on the new earth. It is possible that the marriage supper of the Lamb is the fulfillment of the Passover.

> 17After taking the cup, he gave thanks and said, “Take this and divide it among you. 18For I tell you I will not **drink** again from the fruit of the vine until the kingdom of God comes.”

Yes, I look forward to the eating and drinking with no undue calories in the coming kingdom of God :)

Comment: Are you equating the ‘Passover to come’ with the ‘Marriage supper of the Lamb’? And are you implying that until the ‘Passover to come’ Jesus (and His followers) will never eat together again? That doesn’t seem to follow from the passage you quoted unless they are conflated as one and the same. As such, even if the ‘Passover to come’ in the New Kingdom is on the earth, it speaks nothing of whether the ‘marriage supper of the Lamb’ is also on earth.

Comment: Are you equating the ‘Passover to come’ with the ‘Marriage supper of the Lamb’? No.
And are you implying that until the ‘Passover to come’ Jesus (and His followers) will never eat together again? No.

Comment: The marriage supper of the Lamb happens after Jesus' 2nd coming.

Comment: Whether that is true or not remains for you to make the case and substantiate this with the corresponding text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* difficult question to answer exegetically. Because the whole premise of ‘who’ the bride is is founded on doctrine, traditional interpretation (reasoning), *not* scripture.

Many use various verses such as Paul’s in his letter to the Ephesians to support their view that the ‘bride’ is the church. But those verses that Paul wrote do not specifically, neither even ‘sort of’ provide a foundation for this view - because they are similes. Comparing relationships. ‘This’ is ***like*** ‘this’.

Exegetically there is only one verse that talks about a ‘bride’-

> **REV 21:2 I** *saw the Holy City, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride beautifully dressed for her husband.*

And one verse that talks about the marriage supper (Revelation 19:9). So *just using scripture’ the *only* clear reference to a ‘bride’ (Revelation 21:21) reflects that the associated ‘supper’ is on earth!

Your question makes, or takes the assumption that the *church* is the bride, therefore, from this you could ask whether the *supper* was in heaven. I accept that there are many that believe that the church *is* the ‘bride’, maybe even the majority - it is widely taught! The simple fact is you can *not* argue that the church is the bride exegetically - although you can apologetically argue it *doctrinally*.

Even at a simple level, consider this. The church is Christ’s body. How can the ‘body’ marry itself? This question blatantly confronts doctrine. But, it in no place does it anywhere confront any scripture.

And, what this ‘view’ totally disregards is the Old Testament (Hebrew) concept of ‘marriage’. Which Revelation 19/20 is using (Revelation is written as an Old Testament book!) - that is, the ‘picture’ being portrayed is of ‘oneness’ (Echad). Marriage makes two separate ‘’’ things ‘’’ - one!

Answer (score 1):

While there are many 'seven' in Revelation, seven blessings were proclaimed by the Lord;

1. Rev 1:3 Blessed is the one who reads aloud the words of this prophecy, and blessed are those who hear it and take to heart what is written in it, because the time is near.
2. Rev 14:13 Then I heard a voice from heaven say, “Write this: Blessed are the dead who die in the Lord from now on.” “Yes,” says the Spirit, “they will rest from their labor, for their deeds will follow them.”
3. Rev 16:15 “Look, I come like a thief! Blessed is the one who stays awake and remains clothed, so as not to go naked and be shamefully exposed.”
4. **Rev 19:9 Then the angel said to me, “Write this: Blessed are those who are invited to the wedding supper of the Lamb!” And he added, “These are the true words of God.”**
5. Rev 20:6 Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection. The second death has no power over them, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with him for a thousand years.
6. Rev 22:7 “Look, I am coming soon! Blessed is the one who keeps the words of the prophecy written in this scroll.”
7. Rev 22:14 “Blessed are those who wash their robes, that they may have the right to the tree of life and may go through the gates into the city.

From the progressive revelation of these seven blessings, Rev 19:9 was placed in the middle, and it seems to be the turning point, from promise to the fulfillment. **Now who is the bride of the wedding supper?**

> 2 I saw **the Holy City, the new Jerusalem**, coming down out of heaven from God, **prepared as a bride** beautifully dressed for her husband. (Rev 21:2 NIV)

So the bride is the Holy City, the new Jerusalem, that coming down from heaven. The guest invited are those who have the right to the tree of life and may go through the gates into the city (Rev 22:14). Then my interpretation is;

**- The wedding supper is to be taken place on Earth. The guests are given the fruits on the tree of life (Rev 22:2) to eat, and the water of life (Rev 22:1) to drink.**

Answer (score 0):

Christ weds Himself to His Faithful by dwelling within them spiritually and so they are called the Bride of Christ in Sacred Scripture.  In Rev. 3:20 Christ assures us: "Behold I stand at the door and knock. If any man shall hear my voice and open the door, I will enter in to him and will sup with him, and he with me."  This interior eating is of a spiritual nature as we take up a truth offered us by Grace and as we understand, it becomes a part of us, of our spiritual body/edifice. The New Jerusalem coming down from heaven is both the dwelling of the Bride and is the Bride:  it is the Kingdom of God built of our hearts by the sanctification of the Holy Spirit. He leads us into all Truth and reveals to us by His light the deceits of Satan's temptations as they occur internally before our judgment.  Perhaps there will also be a Wedding Feast upon the entry of the Resurrected Faithful into eternal life.  But we must not postpone this intimate "supping" with Christ offered to us in this our mortal life.  He spreads the feast of His Word before our eyes, and then He gives us grace upon grace to understand it.  Christ said,... "And when He (the Holy Spirit) will come, He will reprove the world of sin, and justice and judgment."(John 16:8)   Is this not a feast?  Thanks be to God!  As to that other feast of Rev. 19:17, does it not refer to the banquet of heresy offered by the Apostate Church in God's name at the end of time?

Comment: While I appreciate you responding, it does not address the question.  I don’t appreciate super-spiritualization of the text. There are real bodies in the new creation. There will be a real banquet with Jesus in a real glorified body among His New Covenant believers (Bride).  Where will this feast be held? In Heaven or on earth?

Comment: What is unreal about spiritual realities?  The eternal verities are immeasurably more real than any temporal creature.  The Holy Spirit is not less real than a physical person, nor are the angels less real, nor are their spiritual acts less real than ours.  Neither God nor the angels have bodies, so what is going on in eternity anyway?  I don't understand your objection.

Answer (score 0):

**Is the marriage supper of the Lamb in heaven or on earth? Rev. 19:9**

**The marriage of the Lamb takes place in heaven. Why?**

Revelation Vs 19:1 says:  "After these things I heard something like a loud voice of a great multitude in heaven, saying,"

The bridegroom, Jesus is now in heaven so those faithful followers promised in marriage must first die and then be resurrected to heaven in the likeness of Jesus. [2 Cor. 11:2,   Rom. 6:5,8]

**Jesus is now in heaven.**

2 Corinthians 11:2 NET

> For I am jealous for you with godly jealousy, because I promised you
> in marriage to one husband, to present you as a pure virgin to Christ.

The Little  Flock [Luke 12:32]  chosen by God  from mankind will be resurrected to heaven in the likeness of Jesus, to live with him

Romans 6:5,8 NASB

> 5 For if we have become united with Him in the likeness of His death,
> certainly we shall also be in the likeness of His resurrection, 8 Now
> if we have died with Christ, we believe that we shall also live with
> Him,

The apostle Paul looked forward to receiving his heavenly resurrection.

2 Timothy 4:8 NASB

> 8 in the future there is reserved for me the crown of righteousness,
> which the Lord, the righteous Judge, will award to me on that day; and
> not only to me, but also to all who have loved His appearing.

Marriage of the Lamb

Revelation 19:7-9 NASB

> 7 Let’s rejoice and be glad and give the glory to Him, because the
> marriage of the Lamb has come, and His [a]bride has prepared herself.”
> 8 It was given to her to clothe herself in fine linen, bright and
> clean; for the fine linen is the righteous acts of the [b]saints.  9
> Then he *said to me, “Write: ‘Blessed are those who are invited to the
> wedding feast of the Lamb.’” And he *said to me, “These are the true
> words of God.” [ Parable of the wedding feast Matthew 22:1-14 ]

**And secondly if it’s called a supper are the guests assumed to consume food and drink? Or not?**

No, this is figurative language, spirit creatures literally do not consume or eat anything in heaven. Reference to in the scriptures of drinking in heaven symbolizes --JOY-- the joy that his resurrected anointed brothers of  Christ will have by being together with him in heaven. [Psalms 104:15]

Comment: The Question is about whether heaven or earth, and this answer says "*die and then be resurrected to **heaven** … will be resurrected to **heaven** … receiving his **heaven**ly resurrection … with him in **heaven***".
Obviously the answer is claiming "heaven", but all instances of that word are supplied by the author, with no scriptural support whatsoever for this claim.
There is no mention of "heaven" in any of the cited verses.
(I.e. it is eisegesis, supporting those that already believe that "heaven" is the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

with this verse:

The heavens belong to the Lord, but the earth he has given to mankind. Psalms 115:16 NET

i would say is on earth. No one goes to Heavens since clearly BELONGS to God of Israel.

Answer (score -1):

The word “Lamb” throughout Revelation is not the regular “technical” word for lamb but a diminutive version that should read something like “Lambkin”. It is an affectionate term used for one’s cherished son. There is an old Jewish joke (I’ve tweaked a bit):

> A Jewish mother and her son are waiting for the school bus to take him
> to school for the first time. She says to him, “Lambkin, look at me.
> You are going to do perfectly fine, Lambkin, and I’ll be here when you
> get back, my precious Lambkin. Hopefully, Lambkin, the other children
> will appreciate what a wonder you are, my dear Lambkin.”
>
> That afternoon he got off the bus and his mother kissed him and hugged
> him and asked, “So what did you learn today, my precious Lambkin?!”
>
> He stammers and replies, “Well, for one thing, I learned that my name
> is David!”

So by referring to Christ as “Lambkin” John is asserting that Jesus is the beloved son of God. So Jesus is the Groom:

> [Mat 9:15 NLT] (15) Jesus replied, "Do wedding guests mourn while celebrating with the groom? Of course not. But someday the groom will be taken away from them, and then they will fast.

> [Jhn 3:28-30 NLT] (28) You yourselves know how plainly I told you, 'I am not the Messiah. I am only here to prepare the way for him.' (29) It is the bridegroom who marries the bride, and the best man is simply glad to stand with him and hear his vows. Therefore, I am filled with joy at his success. (30) He must become greater and greater, and I must become less and less.

> [Jhn 3:29 NLT] (29) It is the bridegroom who marries the bride, and the best man is simply glad to stand with him and hear his vows. Therefore, I am filled with joy at his success.

So who is the bride? We learn about the bride in prophecy:

> [Isa 62:5 NLT] (5) Your children will commit themselves to you, O Jerusalem, just as a young man commits himself to his bride. Then God will rejoice over you as a bridegroom rejoices over his bride.

Jerusalem is the bride. Not the physical city but rather the New Jerusalem:

> [Isa 62:5 NLT] (5) Your children will commit themselves to you, O Jerusalem, just as a young man commits himself to his bride. Then God will rejoice over you as a bridegroom rejoices over his bride.

The New Jerusalem is the New Creation aka the Kingdom of God aka the City on a Hill aka the New Covenant People aka The Israel of God aka The Body of Christ aka God’s Building aka the Heavenly City aka the New Man[kind] aka the Temple Not Made With Hands aka the Freewoman etc:

> [Gal 4:21-27 KJV] (21) Tell me, ye that desire to be under the law, do ye not hear the law? (22) For it is written, that Abraham had two sons, the one by a bondmaid, the other by a freewoman. (23) But he who was of the bondwoman was born after the flesh; but he of the freewoman was by promise. (24) Which things are an allegory: for these are the two covenants; the one from the mount Sinai, which gendereth to bondage, which is Agar. (25) For this Agar is mount Sinai in Arabia, and answereth to Jerusalem which now is, and is in bondage with her children. (26) But Jerusalem which is above is free, which is the mother of us all. (27) For it is written, Rejoice, thou barren that bearest not; break forth and cry, thou that travailest not: for the desolate hath many more children than she which hath an husband.

So what is for dinner? The dinner is the corpses of the ungodly who “Michael and the armies of heaven” (in the form of the Roman army under Titus) will slaughter Circa 70 AD in the Jewish war with Rome. Their bodies will not be buried after the “lake of fire” consumes the city and the birds will come and pluck out their eyeballs and gorge themselves on their flesh:

> [Rev 19:17-21 NLT] (17) Then I saw an angel standing in the sun, shouting to the vultures flying high in the sky: "Come! Gather together for the great banquet God has prepared. (18) Come and eat the flesh of kings, generals, and strong warriors; of horses and their riders; and of all humanity, both free and slave, small and great." (19) Then I saw the beast and the kings of the world and their armies gathered together to fight against the one sitting on the horse and his army. (20) And the beast was captured, and with him the false prophet who did mighty miracles on behalf of the beast--miracles that deceived all who had accepted the mark of the beast and who worshiped his statue. Both the beast and his false prophet were thrown alive into the fiery lake of burning sulfur. (21) Their entire army was killed by the sharp sword that came from the mouth of the one riding the white horse. And the vultures all gorged themselves on the dead bodies.

This feast is also described in Ezekiel:

> [Eze 39:17-24 NASB] (17) "As for you, son of man, thus says the Lord GOD, 'Speak to every kind of bird and to every beast of the field, "Assemble and come, gather from every side to My sacrifice which I am going to sacrifice for you, as a great sacrifice on the mountains of Israel, that you may eat flesh and drink blood. (18) "You will eat the flesh of mighty men and drink the blood of the princes of the earth, as though they were rams, lambs, goats and bulls, all of them fatlings of Bashan. (19) "So you will eat fat until you are glutted, and drink blood until you are drunk, from My sacrifice which I have sacrificed for you. (20) "You will be glutted at My table with horses and charioteers, with mighty men and all the men of war," declares the Lord GOD. (21) "And I will set My glory among the nations; and all the nations will see My judgment which I have executed and My hand which I have laid on them. (22) "And the house of Israel will know that I am the LORD their God from that day onward. (23) "The nations will know that the house of Israel went into exile for their iniquity because they acted treacherously against Me, and I hid My face from them; so I gave them into the hand of their adversaries, and all of them fell by the sword. (24) "According to their uncleanness and according to their transgressions I dealt with them, and I hid My face from them."'"

So to answer the question, no. The wedding feast occurred around 70 AD, when the Old Covenant Jewish Jerusalem temple-based theocracy was judged on their judgment day, causing the Old Covenant to “disappear” forever, and the descent of the New Jerusalem aka the Bride of Christ who would witness the destruction of their persecutors.

> [Mat 21:37-45 KJV] (37) But last of all he sent unto them his son, saying, They will reverence my son. (38) But when the husbandmen saw the son, they said among themselves, This is the heir; come, let us kill him, and let us seize on his inheritance. (39) And they caught him, and cast him out of the vineyard, and slew him. (40) When the lord therefore of the vineyard cometh, what will he do unto those husbandmen? (41) They say unto him, He will miserably destroy those wicked men, and will let out his vineyard unto other husbandmen, which shall render him the fruits in their seasons. (42) Jesus saith unto them, Did ye never read in the scriptures, The stone which the builders rejected, the same is become the head of the corner: this is the Lord's doing, and it is marvellous in our eyes? (43) Therefore say I unto you, The kingdom of God shall be taken from you, and given to a nation bringing forth the fruits thereof. (44) And whosoever shall fall on this stone shall be broken: but on whomsoever it shall fall, it will grind him to powder. (45) And when the chief priests and Pharisees had heard his parables, they perceived that he spake of them.

The wedding feast are the corpses of the enemies of God with which the Messiah littered Jerusalem Circa 70 AD when he participated in the Jewish war with Rome.

Comment: Firstly you have conflated two feasts. Great supper of God with the wedding supper of the Lamb. Yes there will be (future tense), I don’t believe/trust/agree that the preterist view is accurate for the most part. There are few things they are right about because they actually already did happen and it’s documented in history from multiple sources. There will be a great supper of God when there will be great carnage. But to conflate that with the marriage supper and to say it already happened... Even if you’re right about the great supper of God you didn’t address where Marriage supper will be

Comment: @NihilSineDeo In Rome. specifically in the battlefield of Megiddo, Circa 70 AD.

Comment: Did you not understand my comment? There are two feasts. Why are you still addressing the feast I’m not inquiring about?

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been listening. What are the two distinct feasts with which we are concerned?

Comment: I’m asking about the Marriage supper of the Lamb and you are speaking of the Great supper of God. They don’t even have the same name, let alone purpose, guest list and location.

Comment: Okay, let me look into it and I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so the only place "marriage supper of the Lamb" appears is here:  Rev 19:9 NKJV - Then he said to me, "Write: 'Blessed [are] those who are called to the marriage supper of the Lamb!' " And he said to me, "These are the true sayings of God."

Comment: The only place "the Great Supper of God" appears is here: Rev 19:17 NKJV - Then I saw an angel standing in the sun; and he cried with a loud voice, saying to all the birds that fly in the midst of heaven, "Come and gather together for the supper of the great God,

Comment: Aren't they the same feast?

Comment: No, they are not

Comment: I'm open. They are 8 (very short) verses apart. When does the change happen?

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42012/are-the-great-supper-of-god-and-the-wedding-supper-of-the-lamb-the-same-even

Comment: There is a question (sort of) and a non-credible answer at that link. Can you make the case?

Comment: I can make the case they are not one and the same but not here and not now. You also asked when does the change happen, since you’re a preterist it should have already happened, but again no documents in history because both are future events. With respect to each other they appear to overlap but one is in Heaven Marriage supper and the other on earth God’s supper.

Comment: Nonsense. If you can't make the case then you are bluffing.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the Ezekiel passage which is what Rev19:17 is about. So unless you can answer this question why am I being asked to answer a question on another stack. But to make the point because you insist on an answer, however small, (and I’m being compelled against my better judgment) Matthew 22 the parable of the wedding feast, While there was a wedding feast going on the man without the proper attire was cast out into wailing and grinding of teeth. And just prior to that was a massacre. Two separate events by the same person. Two separate locations. Two feasts

Comment: Now explain why they are one and the same. Otherwise you’re not answering the question.

Comment: Okay, so you are concerned about the positive imagery concerning marriage to the Christ. Fair enough. My understanding of that is that the bride of the Lambkin is the New Jerusalem. The New Jerusalem represents the New Covenant People.

Comment: Gal 4:23-26 NLT - The son of the slave wife was born in a human attempt to bring about the fulfillment of God's promise. But the son of the freeborn wife was born as God's own fulfillment of his promise. These two women serve as an illustration of God's two covenants. The first woman, Hagar, represents Mount Sinai where people received the law that enslaved them. And now Jerusalem is just like Mount Sinai in Arabia, because she and her children live in slavery to the law. But the other woman, Sarah, represents the heavenly Jerusalem. She is the free woman, and she is our mother.

Comment: Well, my post was killed off anyway, who gives a damn.